# PDF creation application in C#/.net 4.5?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How to write a pdf file creation application using .net( 4.5 version)
Are there any API available from Adobe or any other 3rd party software is the best.
Thank you,
Smith

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could any one help in converting the data in listview to PDF File?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202860/could-any-one-help-in-converting-the-data-in-listview-to-pdf-file)  (Not an exact dupe, but this question has been asked many times, and this was the first one I found with a good answer.  The answer to the linked question also answers yours.)  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+create+pdf

Answer (score 2):

The best free PDF library for .net is PDFsharp: http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/